# botão de close em menu fixo

Tags: javascript

Olá

Estava a tentar fazer um botão de abrir e fechar um menu fixo com ***javascript*** mas não sei o que estou a fazer de mal com o meu código que não funciona como devia.

Em teoria, quando a *width* da div for maior ou igual a 75px, o botão *onClick* assumia a função de *close* se não assumia a função de *open*.

Código:

```js
/* menu fixo */

var open = document.getElementById("menu-fixo").style.width;

function toggle() {
  if (open >= "75px") {
    document.getElementById("botao-abrir-menu-fixo").onclick = closeNav();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("botao-abrir-menu-fixo").onclick = openNav();
  }
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("menu-fixo").style.width = "75px";
  document.getElementById("botao-abrir-menu-fixo").style.right = "75px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("menu-fixo").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("botao-abrir-menu-fixo").style.right = "0";
}
```

```css
#menu-fixo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 75px;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: width 2s;
}

#botao-abrir-menu-fixo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 75px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  transition: right 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-geral">
  <div id="menu-fixo">menu</div>
  <div id="botao-abrir-menu-fixo" onclick="toggle()">abrir</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta tentando pegar o tamanho através da propriedade style do elemento, só que essa propriedade não existe. Para fazer desse jeito o width deveria estar no elemento dentro de uma propriedade width e right inline nos elementos, assim:

```html
<div id="menu-geral">
  <div id="menu-fixo" style="width: 75px;" >menu</div>
  <div id="botao-abrir-menu-fixo" style="right: 75px;" onclick="toggle()">abrir</div>
</div>
```

#### outras observações:

Se o botão já recebe o `onclick="toggle()"` você pode simplesmente chamar a função dentro do `toggle` dessa forma:

```
function toggle() {
  if (open >= "75px") {
    closeNav();
  } else {
    openNav();
  }
}
```

você deve pegar o botão da DOM toda vez que clicar no botão, se não fizer isso a variável ficara apenas com o estado inicial, e não será atualizada quando mudar de estado.

```
function toggle() {

  var open = document.getElementById("menu-fixo").style.width;

  if (open >= "75px") {
    closeNav();
  } else {
    openNav();
  }
}
```

Por fim sugiro que considere uma abordagem por meio de adição e remoção de classes ( e lembre sempre que estilos por meio de Id tem mais prioridades que por classes. https://medium.com/emanuelg-blog/entendendo-a-preced%C3%AAncia-de-estilo-em-css-especificidade-heran%C3%A7a-e-efeito-cascata-a437c4929173 )

Comment: Funcionou obrigada!